# Galera MariaDB not joining with IST

Tags: mysql, join, galera

Until now, I have a single MariaDB 10.1 node running as Galera Cluster. So, now I want to join the next one.

```
systemctl start mysql
```

initiates the snapshot state transfer (which takes about 10 hours for 200 GBytes).

The config of donor and joiner are quite similar:

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0
[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc_messages_dir = /usr/share/mysql
lc_messages = en_US
skip-external-locking
secure_auth = off
skip-name-resolve
bind-address        = 0.0.0.0
max_connections     = 100
connect_timeout     = 5
wait_timeout        = 600
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_cache_size       = 128
sort_buffer_size    = 4M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 16M
tmp_table_size      = 32M
max_heap_table_size = 32M
myisam_recover_options = BACKUP
key_buffer_size     = 128M
table_open_cache    = 400
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 512M
concurrent_insert   = 2
read_buffer_size    = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 1M
query_cache_limit       = 1G
query_cache_size        = 200M
log_warnings        = 2
slow_query_log=1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
long_query_time = 3
log_slow_verbosity  = query_plan
server-id       = 103
log_bin         = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin
log_bin_index       = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.index
expire_logs_days    = 3
max_binlog_size         = 100M
binlog_format       = ROW
default_storage_engine  = InnoDB
relay_log       = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin
relay_log_index = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin.index
relay_log_info_file = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin.info
log_slave_updates
default_storage_engine  = InnoDB
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 110G
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 8M
innodb_file_per_table   = 1
innodb_file_format  = Barracuda
innodb_open_files   = 400
innodb_io_capacity  = 400
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
[galera]
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_name="dbcluster1"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://"
wsrep_node_name="db1"
wsrep_node_address="db1"
wsrep_replicate_myisam=on
wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup-v2
wsrep_sst_auth=sstuser:pa55w0rt
[sst]
streamfmt=tar
transferfmt=nc
rlimit=3000k
bind-address=0.0.0.0
[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
[mysql]
[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M
```

On the second node, `db1` is replaced by `db2`, it has another `server-id`and

```
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://db1,db2"
```

After doing the SST, the server shuts down cleanly, and the position is stored in `/var/lib/mysql/xtrabackup_binlog_pos_innodb`. However, when I start the server again,

```
systemctl start mysql
```

it does not perform an incremental state transfer, but again flushes the entire data directory `/var/lib/mysql` and starts the SST again.

What do I have to do to join the cluster correctly (with incremental state transfer)?

Comment: My data grow 45 KBytes/sec, so the Galera Cache size of 1 Gigabyte holds for about 6 hours, which is too short, could this be the reason for my problem?

Comment: Well, make the gcache big enough for more than 10 hours, and see if it works.  It's probably a good idea anyway.  The gcache is on disk, so don't worry about RAM limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own hint with the Write Set Cache Size (aka Galera Cache Size) nailed it (I should have asked earlier, it seems some supernatural voice told me the answer.)

However I do not quite understand why 15 GBytes were too few for 45 KBytes/sec for an 18 hours transfer after a next try, obviously it was only a bit too short... (In my question I wrote about 10 hours, which I found out was not true).

Changing the transfer method to `rsync` finally fixed it as the transfer took only 1 hour.